# почему функция равна false?

Tags: php

Есть функция

```
function fun() {
    echo 'a';
}
```

При сравнении

```
if ($z || fun()) {
    echo 'c';
}
```

Должно, по идее, выдать `с`, так как `$z = false,` а `fun()`, по идее, `true`
но при этом `if` выдает `false`
А при проверке

```
if (fun() == false) {
    echo 'false';
}
```

выдает `false`.

Почему эта функция

```
function fun() {
    echo 'a';
}
```

имеет значение `false?`

Comment: Скорее всего, это происходит потому, что fun(), ничего не возвращает, а соответственно интерпретируется как false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, echo - это не функция (это языковая конструкция), echo принимает список аргументов и ничего не возвращает

```
echo 'a';
```

Не возвращает никакого значения, а значит результатом выполнения функции будет `null`

Comment: то есть, если я правильно вас понял, был бы там return , то функция бы вернула результат, и было бы true

Comment: да, если бы `return` вернул что-то, что интерпретировалось бы как true

Answer (score 3):

Для начала обратися к [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php)

> Если конструкция return не указана, то функция вернет значение NULL.

Далее, вы выполняете сравнения

```
if (NULL) ...
if (NULL == false) ...
```

в обоих случаях `NULL` конвертируется в булевский тип и принимает значение `false`. Т.е. первое условие не выполнится (после преобразования получится `if (false)`). А второе условие выполнится (`if (false == false)`)

Если использовать строгое сравнение

```
if (NULL === false) ...
```

то преобразования типов происходить не будет и условие не выполнится